# Assigning values from another variable?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe df like this:

```
>VAR1         VAR2
>38           230
>78           300
>125          600
>173          
>221
>271
>323
>375
>429
>484
>547
>610
```

And i want to assign the values in Var 2 in between the values of Var 1, so that the value in Var2 is smaller than the value in Var1 (but bigger than the value above). So the df has to look sth like this:

```
>VAR1         VAR2
>38           
>78           
>125          
>173          
>221
>271          230
>323          300
>375
>429
>484
>547          
>610          600
```

I've tried "which"-function, but then I had to assign the value manually. This would be an option, of course, but since I have to do this with several df, I thought there might be a function for this. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot.. was my first post here..

Answer (score 1):

I assume your empty rows will be NA values in R.

```
library(dplyr)

# example of dataset
dt = data.frame(Var1 = c(173,221,271,323,375,429,610),
                Var2 = c(230,300,600,NA,NA,NA,NA))

# function that gets the minimum value above a given value x
f = function(x) { min(dt$Var1[dt$Var1 > x]) }
f = Vectorize(f)

# get pairs of Var1 and Var2 values
dt_pairs = data.frame(Var2 = dt$Var2) %>%   # keep only Var2 column as a dataframe
  filter(!is.na(Var2)) %>%                  # filter out NAs
  mutate(Var1 = f(Var2))                    # for each Var2 value get the corresponding value from Var1

# see how the pairs look
dt_pairs

#   Var2 Var1
# 1  230  271
# 2  300  323
# 3  600  610


dt %>%
  select(Var1) %>%                          # select only Var1
  left_join(dt_pairs, by="Var1")            # join the Var2 values   

#   Var1 Var2
# 1  173   NA
# 2  221   NA
# 3  271  230
# 4  323  300
# 5  375   NA
# 6  429   NA
# 7  610  600
```

Comment: Wow, it.worked brilliantly with my data. Thank you so much!